# What exactly is the exponential smoothing model?

Tags: time-series, arima, exponential-smoothing

I see the term "exponential smoothing" model used a lot in different applications but I never understood what exactly it is.  Is it just a MA(1) model?  Or is it any moving average model, meaning it can be any MA model?

For example, the Airline Model has a specific order, which is ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1).  Does the exponential smoothing model have a specific order or characteristics that make it an exponential smoothing model?  What makes an ARMA model an exponential smoothing model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking the name Moving Average is misleading, since it is a moving average of errors, not of values themselves. You can see this by comparing the expressions for MA(1) and Simple Exponential Smoothing:

**Simple Exponential Smoothing**

> $\hat{Y}_t = \alpha Y_t  + (1-\alpha )\hat{Y}_{t-1} $

with $Y_t$ the actual at time t, and $\hat{Y}_t$ the forecast at time t.

**MA(1):**

> $\hat{Y}_t = \mu + \epsilon_t + \theta\epsilon_{t-1}$

with $\hat{Y}_t$ the forecast at time t, and $\epsilon_t = \hat{Y}_t - Y_t$ the error at time t.

Because of this, SES is actually equivalent to ARIMA(0,1,1) not MA(1) with ($\theta =\alpha-1$).

To answer the title question: That is all exponential smoothing is. 
The other more complex exponential smoothing methods, such as double and triple exponential smoothing are variations on this that add trend, seasonality and dampening. As such, exponential smoothing models don't have orders or degrees of complexity the way ARIMA models do.

For the relationship between ARMA/ARIMA and the more general family of exponential smoothing, see [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/10).

Comment: Thank you.  I was also able to find exponential smoothing model is just an ARIMA(0,1,1) model.

Comment: @user6472523 if you find the response satisfying, can you mark it as accepted?

Comment: i thought i did earlier.  just did it

Comment: I saw this while googling for exponential smoothing so just a heads up that there is an absolute equivalence between exponential smoothing models and arima models. See Hyndman's text but I forget the name. Let me find it:  https://www.amazon.com/Forecasting-Exponential-Smoothing-Approach-Statistics/dp/3540719164/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1534960379&sr=8-5&keywords=rob+hyndman

Comment: @mlofton there is significant overlap, but not absolute equivalence. Hyndman mentions it in FPP.

Comment: Hi Alex: There's definitely  equivalence between ARIMA and ES but I guess that depends on how one defines equivalence. I've never read FPP but see Hyndan's "Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing" for all the gory details on the equivalence or this paper: Note that,  If you include SARIMA ( seasonal ), then that does not map directly so maybe that's what Dr. Hyndman is referrring to. But, simple ES is ARIMA(0,1,1), double ES is ARIMA(0,2,2) and I forget what Holt Winters is but it's something also.

Comment: @mlofton ["It is a commonly held myth that ARIMA models are more general than exponential smoothing. While linear exponential smoothing models are all special cases of ARIMA models, the non-linear exponential smoothing models have no equivalent ARIMA counterparts. On the other hand, there are also many ARIMA models that have no exponential smoothing counterparts. In particular, all ETS models are non-stationary, while some ARIMA models are stationary."](https://otexts.org/fpp2/arima-ets.html)

Comment: @alex: I agree that non-linear ES models cannot be re-written as ARIMA models. At the same time, I don't think non-linear ES models are very common. Thanks for quoting. Oh, definitely some ARIMA models cannot be writtten as ES models but I didn't mean to imply that.

Comment: I was under the impression that integrating a moving average process turns it into an autoregressive process; why isn't that the case here? Unless exponential smoothing can somehow also be seen as an autoregressive process.